In Pimcore, while importing data through CSV , XLSX or any http method, its showing Data too large to preview , create a smaller one
I am using Data import bundle and  While previewing data; I'm not able to upload large chunk of data at once  probably tonns of records. How to make it possible! I've adjusted my php.ini file upload_max_size to 500M. But still same issue occuring
I've adjusted my php.ini file upload_max_size to 500M. But still same issue occuring as this is the only solution i got from internet

Please don't use local words like lakh here. Not everyone will understand it.
